# Unable to Unit Test a list.stream with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

```
@Component
ConsumerClass {
private final List<ConsumerService> consumers;
 
public void processConsumers() {

consumers.stream().flatMap(consumer -> Try.of(() -> consumer.receiveMesaages().stream()).
    getOrElseThrow(tx -> { log.error("error");
    return new TransactionException(tx);
}))
.forEach(consumer ->  { processMessages(consumer)})
});

}
```

Note: The consumer.receiveMesaages() return an List

Below is the test:

```
MyTestClass {

@InjectMocks
private ConsumerClass consumersClass;

@Mock
List<ConsumerService> consumers;

@Test
public void testIt() {
List<AxonMessage> axonMessages = new ArrayList<>();
axonMessages.add(axonMessage);
when(consumers.stream()).thenAnswer(inv -> axonMessages.stream());
consumersClass.processConsumers();
}

}
```

I am getting unnecessary stubbing for when().thenAnswer(). Also the code coverage is not achieved for exception as well as forEach(). Can someone please help?

Comment: There isn't enough information in this question for it to be answered.  For one thing, you don't include the source of your `ConsumerService` nor `AxonMessage` classes. Nor have you included your `processMessages` method.  Your `processConsumers` method streams what appears to be a list of messages from a consumer service, but later on in this method, it seems the elements of this list are consumers...?  Your test method is similarly confusing: you are mocking `consumers.stream()` (which would return a `Stream<ConsumerService>`) and telling it to instead return a `Stream<AxonMessage>`.

Comment: It looks as if you've attempted to anonymise 'real' code (which I understand you might have to do) but haven't made a good job of this anonymisation and have also only included part of it in this question. However, perhaps the most fundamental question is why are you mocking the `.stream` method anyway?

Comment: @LukeWoodward Thanks for your response.  I think I got what you are saying and what mistake I made. I will take a look at it and get back.

Comment: ConsumerService is an interface. If I simply create a mock out of it then consumers.stream() returns size()=0 due to which the entire processing logic fails. I want to know How to create a Mock of List<Interface> that is List<ConsumerService> in my example so that I get size()>0 so that remaining logic is executed.

Comment: You are not creating a mock `ConsumerService`. You are creating a mock `List`. Generally there's no need to mock classes that are as fundamental to Java as the collections. You can assume that they just work. So instead create a mock `ConsumerService` and then create a 'real' list such as an `ArrayList` or `Collections.singletonList` containing that. You might not be able to use `@InjectMocks`: instead, just create an instance of `ConsumerClass` in your test setup method and pass in the list to its constructor.